# Download pyodbc on MSYS2 instance of Python 3 using pacman

Tags: python, pyodbc, msys2

I want to install the pyodbc (or pymssql or turbodcb) package for the MSYS2 Python installation, but I can't figure how I can download it. On my regular Python instance, I'm using `pip install pyodbc`. On the MSYS2 instance, I'm trying `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pyodbc` but I'm getting `target not found` error.

How can I download the package?

I need pyodbc to run `pandas.read_sql` statement. So if there is any other package downloadable with pacman that creates connection that `pandas.read_sql` may use, that'll work.

Comment: I am not familiar with `MSYS2`. Have you tried `pacman -S python-pyodbc`? Please ignore if this is not how it works in `MSYS2`

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ thanks for the suggestion, we tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk - Did you find any answer useful? Please post feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling a little bit, and as per

```
$ pacman -Ss pyodbc
```

(see [this](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Using-packages)) there seems to be no `pyodbc` package available for `pacman`.
Check also [this online search tool](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=binpkg&q=pyodbc).

You have the alternative `pip` way, but [the package manager would lose track of what is going on](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2745).

You may try a [virtualenv](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-python-virtualenv) to overcome this hurdle, but I have seen many complaints about `virtualenv` not working in msys2.
I never tried it myself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071486/2707864) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

See whether the relevant mirror (or any) is available in your configuration by checking your mirror list in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`

Update your system with `pacman -Syyu`, then try again.

For more info, read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors

Edit: If this still doesn't work, please post the contents of your mirrorlist here.